# mapping characters across data frames in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe where I have two versions of an id variable (`name1` and `name2`). I want to somehow link these ids so that in a new (much larger) data frame when I encounter `name1` I can create a new column that populates with `name2`.

Here is an example. In `df1` we have `name1` and `name2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name1 = c('AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC'), name2 = c('top', 'mid', 'bottom'))
```

Now I want to make a new larger data frame, `df2` where I have only `name1`, and create a new column that uses the mapping from `df1` to add a new column to `df2`, `name2` which populates using `'AAA' == 'top'; 'AAB' == 'mid'; 'AAC' == 'bottom'`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(name1 = c(rep('AAA', 10), rep('AAB', 10), rep('AAC', 10)))
```

This is obviously a minimal example, the data I am dealing with contains 500k rows and 850 unique ids for `name1` and `name2` so Im looking for something relatively quick.

Comment: Use left join i.e. `left_join(df2, df1)` or `merge(df2, df1, by = "name1", all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: thanks @akrun both options work perfectly.